# Ember.js pass properties between controllers

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Cheers! I have two controllers and I want to have access to `takenSeatsNumbers` from `TravelClient.TourController`.

```
TravelClient.TourController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['tour.seats']
});

TravelClient.TourSeatsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  takenSeatsNumbers: []
});
```

Do I use `needs` in the right way? And how to get `takenSeatsNumbers` from `tour` template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, this is a [current bug](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2025) and so the above will *seemingly* work, but won't work in reality, as the jsFiddle demonstrates. The solution for the moment is to pass in the instance of the controller via `this.controllerFor` in the route. It's far from ideal, but it will suffice for now.

It occurs because Ember refers to controllers using the *dot.notation*, whereas if you use *camelCase* or *under_scores* then it will create you different instances.

The solution is to inject the controller from your route, like so:

```
TravelClient.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
        var tourSeatsController = this.controllerFor('tour.seats');
        tourSeatsController.set('takenSeatsNumbers', [1,2,3]);
        controller.set('tourSeatsController', tourSeatsController);
    }
});
```

And then you can use it in your view as: `{{tourSeatsController.takenSeatsNumbers.length}}`.

Comment: One more dummy question: how could I set `takenSeatsNumbers` back to [] if model in the context of `TourSeatsController` has changed?

Answer (score 0):

This code is based on ember-pre4. The proxying of properties from another controller seems to be a pattern this way and could likely be generalized with the help of a mixin:

```
TravelClient.TourController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['tourSeats'],
  someMethod : function(){
    var tourSeatsController = this.get("controllers.tourSeats");
    // do something with it
  },
  takenSeatsNumbers : function(){ //proxy the property
    return this.get("controllers.tourSeats.takenSeatsNumbers")
  }.property("controllers.tourSeats.takenSeatsNumbers")
});

TravelClient.TourSeatsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  takenSeatsNumbers: []
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Using features of rc.1 I can write only `needs: ['tourSeats']`
and then in the `tour` template: `{{controllers.tourSeats.takenSeatsNumbers}}`

Comment: You need to be careful, because `tourSeats` will be a different instance of the controller: http://jsfiddle.net/CzyWM/ I've posted the temporary solution below, but expect this to be fixed for 1.0: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2025

Comment: This may be a problem with the dot notation. If you don't use it, then it will work. This is a working fiddle based on yours: http://jsfiddle.net/mavilein/CzyWM/1/

Comment: What is actually the point of the dot notation? Why does it exist? I was always fine with the camelcase notation and never had any issues.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with using the *dot.notation*, it's just you should only be using one naming convention to point to a route, to a controller, to a view, or wherever. For example, in your `{{linkTo}}` helper you should be referencing routes with the *dot.notation* (`posts.new`), and so controllers should be referenced in the same way. This is the expected method, but at the moment it is buggy and so we're unable to use the *dot.notation* in `needs`. Ember uses the *dot.notation* internally, and so whilst you've not run into problems, others have not been so fortunate.